# How can i create an animated Real Time Leaderboard Table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to create a simple leader-board table that updates in real-time (or close enough) **However I want it to be animated**. I have been able to create an updating table that updates every second using a simple AJAX script that loads another PHP page. This all works fine and displays the table as it should, but I have no idea how to make it animate up/down if another play has a higher score than them.

What I have done:

**leaderboard.html**

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#Refresh").load("leaderboardupdate.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#Refresh").load('leaderboardupdate.php');
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});

</script>
</html>
```

**leaderboardupdate.php**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Name, Kills FROM Table ORDER BY Kills DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo '<div id="container">';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 


<div class="row">
    <div class="name">'. $row["Name"] .'</div>
    <div class="score">' .$row["Kills"]. '</div>
</div>';

}
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Like I said, this successfully creates a table and updates the data (In order of Kills from the SQL query) as it should, however I am wanting to make a row animate if they have overtaken another player in terms of Kills.

Closest thing I can find as an example:
https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/WbLEvp

I have looked into [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/), which although allows me to have real-time data, I don't think it will allow me to animate the row up/down, and that is the issue I face.

Comment: If you want to animate it, you should get json data from php file and render them with javascript...
Do you really need to update the table every second? I think every 30/60 seconds could be a better solution...

Comment: How many rows, you like to list in the table, ie., in your leaderboard. For ex., Top10 or Top20...

Comment: Well the SQL Query is getting the top 5 best rows in terms of Kills, so 5. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right `sockets.io` won't let you because it is not associated with animation in any way, however they will let you animate by letting your ap know "When to animate". Last time I checked `sockets.io` was meant for `node.js` not sure if they have support for `PHP` or if `PHP` has started supporting `WebSockets`.

`WebSockets` basically establish a connection between your client and server. They work on publish, subscribe model. So your server will open a connection and your client will subscribe to it. Once the connection between server and client is established your server will be able publish changes and client will be able to listen to them. Rough implementation will look something like this. First you will need to open a channel in your client so server and client can communicate through it.

```
<script>
var connection = sockets.open(`user-${userID}`) // will open a channel for some user
// once the connection is established you can listen to events
connection.on('update', function(data) {
 //perfect place to animate stuff and update data
})
```

Then in your backend

```
<?php

$results = $conn->UpdateSomething(); // the place in your code where actions happen;
$socketConnection.trigger($channel, 'update', $results) // this will trigger update event on a $channel with data $results

?>
```

You can also use `ServiceWorkers`, `LongPolling` and `ShortPolling` to listen to real time changes and modify your DOM on events triggered by server

**Steps To Animate**

In order to the actual animation you can follow steps below

1 - Find the dom element containing the new leader, you can easily do it by `getElementById` and giving unique id to each item in board.

2 - Get the previous leader which will ideally be still on top of your leaderboard

3 - Once done, follow this example [Swapping two HTML elements visually and on the DOM, and animate it all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155939/swapping-two-html-elements-visually-and-on-the-dom-and-animate-it-all/19156382#19156382). In this example `clickedDiv` is your new leader and `prev` is your old leader.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time go through it, but how would I actually animate it like in the example I gave in my update answer?

Comment: You basically need to figure which two elements are going to be interchanged i.e new leader with the old leader once done checkout this for animation https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156382/975932

Comment: Do you mind helping me with this? I've no idea of where to even begin and I cannot find anything else that is similar to what I want to do.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I don't think this is going to work for me. 

Instead, is there a way to make it fade in a colour (green) if the row moves up in the list?

Answer (score -1):

[Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) is a useful Library I use for animations. Hope you find it useful.

Also, Try to use socket instead of ajax for real-time data.

Comment: Would that be able to do what the example does in my updated question?

Comment: This is related to sockets AND animation